# My Own Homemade Riddle

Tags: riddle

> I have four hands or two feet and two hands, but I walk on two sometimes all four,
>
> I have some hair or fur you could say but at the same time I don't,
>
> I swing, run, climb, and walk,

**What am I?**

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Answer (score 9):

Are you a

> Chimpanzee?

The walk on both 2 and 4 feet/hands, they swing

> Between branches in trees

They have hair/fur, but not really sure how that fits with the clue that they don’t.

They can also climb as in the comment

Comment: He must be (your answer) of some computer game, that is how it has an hair but also it doesn't.

Comment: Yep, thats it, it could be any monkey or gorilla actually

Answer (score 0):

Are you a:

> Human

My Reasoning:

> Humans have hair but not much. Also, humans walk on all four appendages as infants. They can also do everything listed at the end.

Comment: No, but close. Its like a human but not really a human.